# Hessian quadratic form is well defined

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Could someone show why for the Hessian to be well defined ($d_{p}^{2}f(v,w) = L_{v}L_{w}f$) we need $p$ to be a critical point.

Answer (score 0):

Let $H_p(U, V) = UV f(p)$. Then $H_p(U, gV) = U(gV f) = (Ug)(Vf) + gUVf = gH_p(U, V)$ as $Vf=0$ at $p$. Thus $H_p$ is $C^\infty$ linear and defines a quadratic form. Note that similar argument shows that $H_p$ is symmetric

Comment: i am assuming V is supposed to be the Jacobian, since you mention Vf = 0, and what is U?

Comment: Sorry about the notation, $U$ and $V$ are both vectors fields.

Comment: And $Vf = L_V f$.

Comment: got it. Thanks you very much. One more thing, i am asked to find the Hessian in local coordinates, now i just wrote the Hessian matrix (matrix of second partials), is this generally a correct notation?

Comment: You are correct only when you are at a critical point.

Comment: Generally, it is defined locally to be 
$$H(f,p)=\left.\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}dx^i\otimes dx^j\right|_p,$$
Which is the matrix of partials times that term. Could you explain where that product of forms is coming from?

Comment: That is just a notation, which means that $H(f, p)$ is a quadratic form defined by $H(f, p)(\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}, \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}) =\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}$ at $p$.